# Possible to get the content of sms message (including verification code) sent by authy in a test?

Tags: twilio, capybara, minitest, authy

I have an app that sends an SMS with a verification code to users during signup.

I send it by doing the following:

```
Authy::API.request_sms(:id => user.authy_id)
```

I was wondering if it is possible to see the exact content of this SMS (along with the verification code) during my testing, so that I could just directly put the code into the input field when I run my capybara signup test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We are [dealing with this query over on GitHub here](https://github.com/twilio/authy-ruby/issues/54), but I thought I would add my answer here in case it helps others.

Unfortunately the API does not expose the code or the text of the message sent to the user.

However, I wouldn't recommend testing third party services, even as part of your end to end testing. Given the reliance on a network in order to call the API, that you'd be testing a third party library (this one) and the fact that this would trigger an SMS in real life, it doesn't lend itself to good tests.

Instead I would mock the API response for both the sending and verifying part of the test.